# What is best way to apply ngif directive to <li> element?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I have a structure like this:

```
class GrandParent{
  childsOfGrandParent: Parent[];
}

class Parent{
  child: Child;
}

class Child{
 x:number
 y:number
 z:number
}
```

If we have object like this in .ts

```
  grandParent: GrandParent[] = [];
```

and in html:

```
<ul *ngFor="let parent of grandParent.childsOfGrandParent; let i = index;">

      <li  *ngIf="parent.child"> 
           {{child.x}}</li>
      <li  *ngIf="parent.child"> 
           {{child.y}}</li>
      <li  *ngIf="parent.child"> 
           {{child.z}}</li>

    </ul>
```

What should I  do if we do not want to repat ngIfs int this structure?

Comment: `<li *ngIf="condition">` ...

Comment: I have already applied this, I am looking for more proper way. I do not want to repat ngIfs condirions  per each  <li> elements

Answer (score 3):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="parent.child">
      <li>{{child.x}}</li>
      <li>{{child.y}}</li>
      <li>{{child.z}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Ozmen no problem, considering accepting an answer to close your question (and upvote mine if it helped you)